Extraterrestrial organisms similar to humans and design
If we ever confirm that intelligent extraterrestrial organisms similar to ourselves are living on other planets, is that a fact which would make our being designed along with them more probable? For instance, let's say they not only have equal or greater intelligence, but body plans (e.g. one head, four limbs, at least two sets of digits for tool use), something we see in most science fiction. We don't need to hold the designer would be a deity for the question. A far more advanced lifeform much older than us would do, if they tweaked evolution or something like that over eons.

Or, it could just be convergent evolution. And so far we have not encountered extraterrestrial organisms of any kind and have no idea what they look like, if they exist, or what environments they reside in, to judge whether they could naturally evolve there. So what is the point of idle speculation?

This might get more interesting answers in Worldbuilding SE, with slight rewording.

There is a lot more life in oceans, and for a longer time than land. Mammals are a fluke of the asteroid impact 65 mya. I would speculate that something like an octopus is the most likely intelligence apex, they have 9 brains, after all. Not sure if they could ever build space ships though. Land is better for that.

@Conifold convergent evolution seems to be more palatable way of saying  the Infinite monkeys did it twice.

No, it is a way of saying that similar environments produce similar adaptations. Or, if you prefer, that running a dynamical system twice on similar inputs produces similar outputs.

Needs clarity: "similar to ourselves" is quite subjective: "similar" means just being solids? having limbs? Having four limbs?

Well if life can start and evolve here, certainly it seems more plausible to presume that it also happened elsewhere. It atleast seems more plausible than speculating about a super deity in a presumably unknown realm that would beg for an explanation just as much as the aliens you posit.

In the ocean, given enough time, every crustacean eventually looks like a crab... maybe on land, given enough time, every mammal eventually looks like a human?  https://www.popsci.com/story/animals/why-everything-becomes-crab-meme-carcinization/

@Conifold Or, if you prefer, that running a dynamical system twice on similar inputs produces similar outputs . i.e. Intelligent Design.

@Conifold - No, it is a way of saying that similar environments produce similar adaptations  What are adaptations? How do they arise?

@RodolfoAP - the OP was quite specific : let's say they not only have equal or greater intelligence, but body plans (e.g. one head, four limbs, at least two sets of digits for tool use)   Regardless of the precise description, the question remains, even if we were to encounter so called primitive life forms akin to those on earth, which upon close examination prove to be exceedingly complex.

Having hands is vastly more useful than having feet. Trading two of your 4 feet for 2 hands is such an enormous improvement in capability that after it happens, that species would likely, you know, subjugate the planet, produce culture and technology, and go on to delude itself with tv and social media.  Then it would say how amazing it was that even God has a special place for it in the scheme of things. It is inevitable. Quadrupeds don't do that.

Not at all. The fact that intelligent extraterrestrial life evolved on other planets, even with similarities to humans in basic body plan, would be entirely explicable by the theory of evolution by natural selection. It would simply mean that natural selection, acting over billions of years in different environments, happened to converge on broadly similar solutions for intelligent tool-using species.
This is not at all surprising or unexpected given the constraints imposed by physics and chemistry. Of course intelligent tool-makers would tend to have manipulating appendages like arms and hands. Of course they would have a concentrated information processing center like a brain/head to control the body. These are the kinds of features that would evolve by non-random survival of random variants.
The whole idea of 'tweaking' evolution implies the very sort of misguided argument from improbability that was refuted time and again. Yes, the emergence of complex statistical improbabilities like human intelligence is extremely improbable when you look at it retrospectively. But evolution is a simple, comprehensible process which, given enough time, can crank away and produce conscious, intelligent beings from simple replicating beginnings.
To suggest that the existence of other evolved intelligences makes us 'designed' is just rehashing the long-discredited argument from complexity and improbability. It commits the corrupt statistical reasoning of only looking at things retrospectively and ignoring the simple power of cumulative selection over billions of years to raise improbabilities. It's just the modern day version of saying 'The universe must have been designed because it's so improbable.'

misguided argument from improbability that was refuted time and again Has it truly been refuted?  See; Has the Argument From Improbability been Debunked?, among numerous others. What some consider "misguided", others consider entirely reasonable and probable.

I don't know why people worship the idea of randomness. The weather on any particular day is basically random, yet we have predictable average high and low temps and rainfall, seasons that recur within days of the same dates each year, for millennia... So, someone must have their hands on the weather machine? The bigger a system is, the less random it is. We can predict eclipses a thousand years from now with one minute accuracy.

This answer is based on circular reasoning: This is not at all surprising or unexpected given the constraints imposed by physics and chemistry . Granted. However perhaps the constraints imposed by physics and chemistry are determined by an 'intelligent designer'. It is impossible to prove otherwise, since we live in a universe under constraints imposed by physics and chemistry. Such was the opinion of Spinoza Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy-Baruch Spinoza-God or Nature and Einstein, much influenced by the thought of Spinoza.

What do people get out of the idea of an intelligent designer? What does it do for them? I think this is the real question that demands an answer. If we understood why people are attached to unfruitful ideas, maybe we could make some progress in solving the world's actual problems.

@ScottRowe What do people get out of the idea of an intelligent designer? I suggest you post this question on one of the SO sites concerning religion. I'm sure you will get many answers, some good, some not so good, and some outright ridiculous.

@ScottRowe Well, I think the reason people cling to this patently absurd idea of an 'intelligent designer' behind the natural world is that it provides a deeply comforting delusion. It's an easy way out, you see? Instead of having to grapple with the terrifying randomness and contingency of our existence, people can just tell themselves that everything happens for a reason and is part of some grand cosmic plan.

@ScottRowe - this might help answer your question: Richard Dawkins laments decline of 'cultural Christianity' in UK amid surging Islam. Without such 'nonsensical notions' as Christianity, there could be no 'cultural Christianity'. Which makes Dawkins  claim that he is ""happy" the number of practicing Christians in the U.K. is plummeting hypocritical and ridiculous: If there are no 'practicing Christians', there can be no 'Christian Culture' - DUH.

@Groovy - You have declined to address my objections to your answer, yet you blithely claim the notion of IDesigner is patently absurd.  Please defend your answer rationally before dismissing a claim as patently absurd . Such behavior proves that you have no retort other than your own personal feelings, which have no place in this forum.

@Vector so you suggest that "outright ridiculous" (from your comment) is better than "patently absurd" (from Groovy's comment), I'm guessing?

@ScottRowe - Poor comparison: patently absurd concerns a logical contention.  ridiculous only means worthy of ridicule.  (I didn't say 'outright' - you added that.) Regardless, my comment about Dawkins's position is irrelevant to anything Grooby said - unlike Dawkins, Grooby has not performed a juggling act regarding Christianity.

But evolution is a simple, comprehensible process which, given enough time, can crank away and produce conscious, intelligent beings from simple replicating beginnings i.e. - the old saw: Given enough time, anything can happen. The infinite monkeys win!

@Vector 'outright' was in an earlier comment you made in this thread. The Monkeys idea does not include the ideas of selection and successive refinement that Evolution relies on. An example from math would be the difference between trying every possible point in a function vs using Newton-Raphson. Evolution builds. "Nothing Succeeds Like success" If you have a process which uses prior outputs as input, it pretty much has to converge on an answer, something random choice cannot do. So it's more like Infinite Hundredth Monkey.

@ScottRowe  If you have a process which uses prior outputs as input, it pretty much has to converge on an answer, something random choice cannot do. So it's more like Infinite Hundredth Monkey - Which begs the question how did the 'prior output' originate? Which goes back to this, and a multitude of similar questions, which have been bandied about for millenia: If God is non-physical, does God become unnecessary as a cause? Round and round we go.... LOL

@ScottRowe - Note that the Newton Raphson Method works when there is meaningful input - a reasonable approximation of the result you are seeking. Also, it only refines the initial approximation. It is not magic - it does not transform meaningless input into meaningful output. So again...

@Vector death removes the also-rans. It's the same process humans have used to get skinny dogs and cats with fluffy coats. If the natural environment calls for a fluffy coat, it will end up that way. The world is big and time is long. It would be surprising if it wasn't so.

@ScottRowe - It's the same process humans have used to get skinny dogs and cats with fluffy coats - that was Darwin's analogy. It was roundly debunked by Samuel Wilberforce - Contra Darwin The popular view may be that Huxley had the better of the exchange; but there is a consensus view of historians that this account of the debate involves later fabrication, and that the outcome was moot.  Later academics felt more comfortable with 'scientism' so they pushed Darwin/Huxley.

@ScottRowe death removes the also-rans - Be nice if there was something in the fossil record to confirm that. To claim to everything that wasn't exactly to spec immediately died without a trace while thousands upon thousands of 'viable' examples were preserved is up there with 'infinite monkeys', especially if one contemplates the complexity of life and how many stages it takes to get just from one 'primitive' cell to multi-cell organisms, IMO believing such notions requires more faith than Christianity does. It's Scientism.

@ScottRowe It's the same process humans have used to get skinny dogs and cats with fluffy coats  i.e. Intelligent Design. LOL

@Vector "Reports from the time suggest that everybody enjoyed themselves immensely, and all went cheerfully off to dinner together afterwards." I think this is the point we are at now.

Let's ignore the issue of how one would show an origin relationship between life from different planets. Mere structural similarity is probably not enough because there might be evolutionary explanations for that, but let's just assume that xenobiologists determined that some extra-terrestrial life shows evidence of being related to earth life, meaning that it is extremely unlikely that they had entirely unrelated origins, and further than the similarities cannot be explained merely by material moving from one planet to another. There are, for example, rocks on earth that came from Mars, so let's assume that such explanations will not be sufficient.
In this case, there would be strong evidence of an intelligent designer, but not a supernatural one. There would be a natural explanation in terms of an unknown intelligent species that was involved in designing all of the related life or at least in transporting the life from one planet to another. It's hard to imagine any evidence that would rule out that explanation in favor of a supernatural one.

In this case But the OP did not asked about that specific case.  in favor of a supernatural one : The OP specifically said:  We don't need to hold the designer would be a deity for the question   . These points appear to make this answer somewhat irrelevant.

It seems that you consider humans a kind of prototype species in the universe.

Because you base your post right from the beginning on the assumption
that the extraterrestrial being are similar to humans. That’s a
rather anthropocentric viewpoint. It makes your thought experiment
totally unlikely and less meaningful.

We learn from biological evolution on earth that the shape of animals
develops in adaption to their ecological niche. And the similarity
of their blueprint results from common ancestors.

Hence I would    broaden the scope of the question. The context of
your question would then be life on the planets of other stars,
possibly from other star generations in the galaxy.
I would
substitute the anthropomorphic viewpoint by the viewpoint of cosmic
evolution.



He didn't assume that any extraterrestrial beings would be similar to humans; he made that the premise of the question: "If they are similar to humans, then...".

@David Gudemann I know. But this a priori assumption makes the whole thought experiment totally unlikely. - There could be more behind the question.

This is a comment, not an answer.

Before the Permian Extinction, there were 24 animal body plans, now there are 4. Had that extinction not occurred, there would likely be a lot more varieties of living things and humans certainly would never have arisen. The thought experiment defeats itself in its own playing field.

We are on the brink of being able to redesign and augment our bodies, with germ-line genetic engineering (substantial steps were taken in  Korea by Hwang Woo-suk) and computer-brain interface developments like Neuralink are working on. And we haven't even established a permanent self-sufficient colony off-planet, never mind reached the stars.
Arthur C Clarke's Von Neuman replicator black-obelisks in the 2001 sequence are more likely than fellow bipeds. Or the sentient machinery in the Expanse books.
There's a serious proposal as part of the OrchOr model of consciousness, that neutron star tectonics and vibrations could be used for computations, so they create vast simulations, or even be conscious at a scale beyond our comorehension. Rupert Sheldrake published a paper on 'Is the Sun Conscious?' which he presents as a speculative proposal to see whether we can truly answer. He identifies as cosmological significance that conscious stars could be controlling their solar flares to navigate, speeding up orbits in a way that explains the appearance of Dark Matter, as phantom additional mass.
But, a truly advanced civilisation might choose avatars that make us comfortable, they might put us into simulations or directly access our minds using the familiar things to us to represent themselves. If we encounter beings anything like ourselves, it's likely this, like we treat our pets by mimicing their body language to reassure them about a world they couldn't possibly comprehend the true mechanics of.

Maybe, but I'm thinking a truly advanced civilization wouldn't notice or pay any attention to us. Unless they "need humanity help" (Arrival).

@ScottRowe: Yes exactly right! Corrected. In the 2001 books the obelisks are basically gardening sentient species, for unknown purposes. They seperate an ice-moon in our Solar System with another lineage of life into it's own solar system, to protect it from humana long enough to develop. What would really advanced humans do? Probably crazy over-elaborate hobbies right. A star-faring species asking us for help would be about as likely as us asking an ant to do something really crucial for us.

Mold does really crucial things for us, sometimes. It never hurts to ask. My gut biome is making 95% of my serotonin. But it keeps asking for Swedish Fish.

This is an interesting ramble, but makes no attempt to answer the question.

I actually think the question is unanswerable.

For a statistical analysis, we need at least two clear choices. In this case, the choices are random happenstance and an "intelligent designer".
The case of the OP would seem to be an excellent argument for some sort of intelligent designer - make it much more probable than random happenstance.
To represent random happenstance, let's use the Infinite monkey theorem

The infinite monkey theorem states that a monkey hitting keys at
random on a typewriter keyboard for an infinite amount of time will
almost surely type any given text, including the complete works of
William Shakespeare. In fact, the monkey would almost surely type
every possible finite text an infinite number of times. The theorem
can be generalized to state that any sequence of events that has a
non-zero probability of happening will almost certainly occur an
infinite number of times, given an infinite amount of time or a
universe that is infinite in size...
In fact, there is less than a one in a trillion chance of success that
such a universe made of monkeys could type any particular document a
mere 79 characters long

The humanoid form - one head, four limbs, at least two sets of digits for tool use, and (since the OP specified organism, some sort of biological entity) all its necessary internal workings, such as the brain, the digestive system, the nervous system etc. - all encoded in our DNA - clearly represent an organized entity, far more complex than a 79 character document:
By way of example:
Human genome

The current version of the standard reference genome is called
GRCh38.p14 (July 2023). It consists of 22 autosomes plus one copy of
the X chromosome and one copy of the Y chromosome. It contains
approximately 3.1 billion base pairs (3.1 Gb or 3.1 x 109 bp). This
represents the size of a composite genome based on data from multiple
individuals but it is a good indication of the typical amount of DNA
in a haploid set of chromosomes. Most human cells are diploid so they
contain twice as much DNA.

Therefore, the probability of a similar combination (the humanoid form - one head, four limbs, at least two sets of digits for tool use) occurring even once at random (or at the rate of the Infinite monkey theorem - as you prefer), is far less than one in a trillion. Do the math for calculating the probability of a similar combination occurring twice. I cannot do that at the moment, but the probability of similar combinations occuring twice at random is extremely remote.
In terms of probability, the alternative to random happenstance (AKA The Infinite Monkey Theory) an intelligent designer of some sort is far more probable.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.


...fact which would make our being designed along with them more
probable?

I think the fact that after decades of scanning the universe we did not find any intelligent signals in space, indicates that we live in some kind of bubble (not a natural world). Given the trillions of worlds we can observe, according to a natural order (without deities), we would already detect some intelligent signals on radio or other spectrum.

-1 - You have overlooked the numerous solutions to Fermi's Paradox, which is what you are asking: "But where is everybody?" See The Fermi Paradox and the Great Filter Theory Explained for starters.

We can't detect signals very far away. There are not a lot of good planet candidates in our neighborhood. Maybe we need to move downtown?

@ScottRowe -Check out the article I cited in my comment here. It lists several reasons that we don't necessarily detect such signs or signals, among them yours. Also The zoo hypothesis suggests that intelligent civilizations are observing us without revealing their presence . In fact, a whole book has been written to solve The Fermi Paradox : --If the Universe Is Teeming with Aliens ... WHERE IS EVERYBODY?: Seventy-Five Solutions to the Fermi Paradox and the Problem of Extraterrestrial Life--

@Vector right, I saw another estimate recently that the chance that the Earth is the only planet in the universe - the universe - with intelligent life is 50%. (depending on whether we're intelligent, I guess) "Space is big. You just won't believe how vastly, hugely, mind-bogglingly big it is."

But yeah, we definitely live in "some kind of bubble". The social media kind. Which is blocking all the signals the universe sends us about reality.

@ScottRowe intelligent life is 50%  Considering the size of the universe, that seems a very conservative estimate.

@Vector right, but it seems that we have no idea what a good estimate might be. But there could be bazillions of intelligent races, all hopelessly far apart from each other, which amounts to the same thing. A can of food does me no good if I'm lost in the woods without a can opener.
